# Less Variables on left side

Tags: css, less

I admit I am fairly new to less. While playing with it to make my site as dynamic as possible I was trying to use less variables so if I had to change something I could just do it in one file.

I have run across an issue though when trying to position elements. For example  I have a button that is currently sitting on the left side, but in the future I may want to move it to the right. Normally how you call that is either `left:0;` or `right:0;`

Is there a way to make that left, or right a variable?

My css looks like this

```
.previous{
    position:fixed; 
    left:0; //The left is what I want to declare somewhere else
    top:@header-padding; 
    height:@side-height; 
    font-size: @button-side-font !important;
}
```

I have tried something like

```
@{prevPos}: left;
```

and then calling

```
@prevPos: 0;
```

but it just stopped loading my application altogether.

Comment: See [Property Interpolation](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-properties).

Comment: @seven-phases-max That is what I cant get to work

Comment: Most likely because you use an outdated Less compiler.

Comment: @seven-phases-max I can assure you that is not the cause.

Comment: See the working [codepen](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/ldLmB).

Comment: @seven-phases-max it may work fine there, but it's still not working right in my code.

Comment: So you are sure that the problem is not in an outdated compiler. Could you name it and its version please?

Comment: @seven-phases-max I am positive, we just created this app a few days ago. I did not set up where it's being rendered though in our architecture so I'm not sure where to find it.

Answer (score 1):

**Mixins (update)**

Have you tried using a [mixin](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature)?

It could look something like this:

```
.previous {

    .previous-position();

    font-size: @button-side-font !important;
    height:    @side-height;
    position:  fixed;
    top:       @header-padding;
}

.previous-position() {
    left: 0;
    // right: 0;
}
```

To swap the left and right, change the comment in the mixin.

**Multiple classes approach (original answer)**

I'd actually approach this differently. Instead of having the button styles *and* positioning in the same CSS rule, I'd have the positioning in a sub-class.

```
.previous {
    font-size: @button-side-font !important;
    height:    @side-height;
}

.previous-left,
.previous-right {
    position: fixed;
    top:      @header-padding;
}

.previous-left {
    left: 0;
}

.previous-right {
    right: 0;
}
```

Then your buttons look like this:

```
<a href="#" class="previous previous-left">I am on the left</a>
<a href="#" class="previous previous-right">I am on the right</a>
<a href="#" class="previous">I am not fixed</a>
```

This way you can update your page pretty quickly without having to tear apart your LESS files and it makes your styles more re-usable.

Comment: I cannot add separate classes and the whole point was that they would have to just change one word in one file instead of digging through several files when something changes.

Comment: Can I call that function in another class? I tried adding it in my variable file and then calling it in my main file and it gives me the error Unrecognised input

Comment: It should be fine and it should be possible to add it to any class, regardless of it's name (unless you call your class `previous-position`, the same as the mixin name). Adding it to the variables file (or a "mixins" file next to teh variables file) is certainly where I would have added it.

Answer (score 0):

And yet another answer for how to get it to work in a "variable way" using old-fashioned method (intentionally using the most conservative syntax so it could work even with ancient compilers):

```
@previous-position: right;

.previous {
    position:  fixed;
    margin:    1em;
    font-size: 400%;

    .-(left)  {left:  0}
    .-(right) {right: 0}
    .-(@previous-position);
}
```